# How to connect to mysql created by docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I can not connect to Mysql created with Docker in local environment (Mac OS X).

I have created the following configuration file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysqldatabase
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "33333:3306"
    container_name: mysql-db
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
```

Then, I started the docker container of mysql with the following command.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker start mysql-db
```

Up to this point there was no problem, but an error occurred when trying to connect to mysql.

```
$ mysql -p 33333 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Please tell me how to deal with it.

Comment: Try "mysql -h 0.0.0.0 -P 33333 -u root -p". Note port here has upper case P and password has lower case.

Comment: @harshavmb I was able to connect! What a rudimentary mistake!

Comment: Glad to see it helped you!

Comment: Side note, the latest version of Docker Compose is 3, you might want to check out the [Compose File Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `mysql -h 0.0.0.0 -P 33333 -u root -p`.

Note port here has upper case P and password has lower case p.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you connect from the host to the container. mysql will see the connection from non-local host, so disconnect it. You can change mysql config to allow other hosts, or connect from inside that container using `docker exec -it mysql ...`